# Setting in and out easing separately

Tags: unity-game-engine, tween, leantween

When using [LeanTween](http://dentedpixel.com/LeanTweenDocumentation/classes/LeanTween.html) for Unity to move a GameObject, is it possible to set the in and out parts of the easing separately?

What I would like to do is:

1. Start off slow.
2. Gradually increase speed from slow to fast.
3. Stop abruptly with no ease at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should make your own animation curve on LeanTween.

Just create a `AnimationCurve` to edit in the editor:

```
public AnimationCurve animCurve;
 
void Start(){
    LeanTween.scale(gameObject, Vector3.zero, 1f).setEase(animCurve);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds like Ease-in-sine, like so:

```
LeanTween.move(this.gameObject, new Vector2(0f, 5f), 2f).setEaseInSine();
```

This moves the gameobject the way you describe it: Slowly starting, accelerating and abruptly stopping.

When typing ".setEase", your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) should suggest you ways to complete the code (See Screenshot). There you will find many different presets of easing-curves. Like only easing in, only easing out, or both combined.
If you are not sure what easing to use, you can look at a collection of some of the most used easing-curves here: https://easings.net/en

Like [@Lotan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7878320/lotan) already suggested, creating your own animation curves would give you the ability to fully customize the easing behavior.

[image]